# What exactly is backoffcriteria and how it works?

Tags: android, jobs, evernote

Currently i am implementing Android-Job, an Evernote service Library [Evernote- AndroidJob](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)

For those of you who don't know or haven't had a nightmare about background services, it is a Utility library which can run jobs delayed in the background.

There are many setting while creating a Job, I am little unsure about the backoffcriteria() setting.
How does it work?

What could be the use-case for this?

If I know when to reschedule the Job Do I need to I need it? And How to reschedule the Jobs regarding Android Job?

Answer (score 0):

Backoff Criteria is essentially how many times it should retry if it fails for some reason.

If you have backoff set as exponential, I think it'll keep retrying forever until it's successful.